# How to set the Android progressbar's height?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

My `activity_main.xml` is below, as you see, the height is set 40 dip.

And in MyEclipse, it looks like below:

[image]

But when I run it on my phone, it looks like below:

[image]

So my question is why the real height of the progressbar is not the one I set? How to increase the height of the progressbar?

Comment: progressBar.setScaleY(2f); integer represents height

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From [this tutorial](https://a-renouard.developpez.com/tutoriels/android/custom-progress-seek-bar/):

```
<style name="CustomProgressBarHorizontal" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
      <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_progress_bar_horizontal</item>
      <item name="android:minHeight">10dip</item>
      <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
</style>
```

Then simply apply the style to your progress bars **or better**, override the default style in your theme to style all of your app's progress bars automatically.

The difference you are seeing in the screenshots is because the phones/emulators are using a difference Android version (latest is the theme from ICS (Holo), top is the original theme).

Comment: Use this style..  style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse" . its worked for me

Comment: Here is a free alternative to that custom_progress_bar_horizontal drawable:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android

Answer (score 223):

I guess the simplest solution would be:

```
mProgressBar.setScaleY(3f);
```

Comment: In fact this is the only solution. Thanks for sharing

Comment: This answer, at only 4f, made my bar unbearable fuzzy, almost like it had a glow style on it.

Comment: @beyondtheteal hehe, but the height actually DID change, isn't it? So I don't understand why you vote the answer down. If you need a bar that is highly scaled, you may create your own "CustomProgressBar".

Comment: notice that if you're gonna draw something on top of it (e.g. circle) you're gonna get scaled version of it (i.e. ellips)

Comment: simple solution, nice.. you can also directly add - android:scaleY="3"

Answer (score 84):

android:scaleY="8" in your xml file

Answer (score 31):

You can use the **`LinearProgressIndicator`** provided by the Material Components Library and the **`app:trackThickness`** attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
    android:indeterminate="true"
    app:trackThickness="xxdp"
    ../>
```

With `12dp`:

[image]

With `4dp`:

[image]

**Note:** it requires at least the version **`1.3.0-alpha04`**.

Answer (score 21):

Use this

`style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"`

Comment: What does your answer have to do with setting custom height on the ProgressBar?

Comment: This solves the issue. Could you explain why this works?

Comment: @Alfred it works because the style is different. The drawn part of the Widget ProgressBar stretches to fit the entirety of layout_height, while the regular Android ProgressBar does not.

Comment: This solution works!! previously i was using `?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal`, this doesnt work

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in other answers, it looks like you are setting the style of your progress bar to use Holo.Light:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
```

If this is running on your phone, its probably a 3.0+ device. However your emulator looks like its using a "default" progress bar.

```
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
```

Perhaps you changed the style to the "default" progress bar in between creating the screen captures? Unfortunately 2.x devices won't automatically default back to the "default" progress bar if your projects uses a Holo.Light progress bar. It will just crash.

If you truly are using the default progress bar then setting the max/min height as suggested will work fine. However, if you are using the Holo.Light (or Holo) bar then setting the max/min height will not work. Here is a sample output from setting max/min height to 25 and 100 dip:

max/min set to 25 dip:
[image: 25 dip height progress bar]

max/min set to 100 dip:
[image: 100 dip height progress bar]

You can see that the underlying drawable (progress_primary_holo_light.9.png) isn't scaling as you'd expect. The reason for this is that the 9-patch border is only scaling the top and bottom few pixels:

[image: 9-patch]

The horizontal area bordered by the single-pixel, black border (green arrows) is the part that gets stretched when Android needs to resize the .png vertically. The area in between the two red arrows won't get stretched vertically.

The best solution to fix this is to change the 9patch .png's to stretch the bar and not the "canvas area" and then create a custom progress bar xml to use these 9patches. Similarly described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18832349

Here is my implementation for just a non-indeterminant Holo.Light ProgressBar. You'll have to add your own 9-patches for indeterminant and Holo ProgressBars. Ideally I should have removed the canvas area entirely. Instead I left it but set the "bar" area stretchable.
https://github.com/tir38/ScalingHoloProgressBar

Answer (score 13):

Many solution here with lot of upvotes didn't work for me, even the accepted answer. I solved it by setting the scaleY, but isn't a good solution if you need too much height because the drawable comes pixelated.

**Programmatically:**

---

```
progressBar.setScaleY(2f);
```

**XML Layout:**

---

```
android:scaleY="2"
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<ProgressBar  
android:minHeight="20dip" 
android:maxHeight="20dip"/>
```

Comment: This is not working!
Answer from Piraba is easy to implement and works like a charm.

Comment: Nah, this does not control the height of a horizontal Progressbar.

Answer (score 7):

This is the progress bar I have used.

```
<ProgressBar
     android:padding="@dimen/dimen_5"
     android:layout_below="@+id/txt_chklist_progress"
     android:id="@+id/pb_media_progress"
     style="@style/MyProgressBar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:progress="70"
     android:scaleY="5"
     android:max="100"
     android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/white"
     android:progressTint="@color/green_above_avg" />
```

And this is my style tag

```
 <style name="MyProgressBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressBackgroundTint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:progressTint">@color/green_above_avg</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

values->styles.xml

```
<style name="tallerBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">8dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
</style>
```

Then in your ProgressBar add:

```
style="@style/tallerBarStyle"
```

Comment: Good answer, but also more complete.

Comment: Doesn't have an effect on horizontal Progressbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can set progress bar's style to this:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the height from XML using

```
android:layout_height="20dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap the Progressbar with a Viewgroup,and dynamic change the Viewgroup's height

xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/clClaim"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-2dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:visibility="visible">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/shape_progress_arena_claim"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clClaimContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_stroke5751b5_top12dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivClaim"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_65"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_58"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_17"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_5"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dsc_square"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_12"
            android:text="@string/Claim_your_free_DSC_now"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_14"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivClaim"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/ivClaim"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivClaim" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvClaim"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_17"
            android:background="@drawable/default_button_selector5"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/dp_15"
            android:paddingVertical="@dimen/dp_7"
            android:text="@string/Claim"
            android:textColor="@color/default_text_selector"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_12"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivClaim"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivClaim" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

java:

```
        mBinding.clClaim.post(() -> {
        int navHeight = ScreenUtils.getNavHeight2(this);
        int clHeight = mBinding.clClaimContent.getHeight();
        mBinding.clClaim.getLayoutParams().height = clHeight + navHeight + DensityUtils.dp2px(2);
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFsbv.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW8z6.png)