# Remove vertical padding from horizontal ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

By default the ProgressBar has a certain padding above and below the bar itself. Is there a way to remove this padding so as to only have the bar in the end?

Comment: As noted in other topics, setting `maxHeight`, does not work.

Comment: `android:minHeight="4dp"`

Answer (score 76):

I use the following as a workaround for this issue.

```
android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
```

Comment: I didn't need layout_marginBottom.

Comment: `android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"` worked for me. Wonder whether it's dependent on device? I have only tested on Xperia Z1

Comment: @ThorbjørnKappelHansen It is device dependent. Galaxy S6 and a margin top of -6dp does not work as desired.

Comment: I think the margins would depend on the size of the progress bar and android version.

Comment: using `Framelayout` (like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36264357/4112725) is better solution and not depend on phone size/type/os version

Comment: a better solution is
<ProgressBar style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal" android:layout_height="4dp"/>

Comment: @AbandonedCart my solution will not remove padding but forcing height to a specific value padding are overridden

Comment: @Xan That is not true. You are exploiting a safety net in the framework that prevents you from doing something unintentional, such as creating a view that is negated by its own default padding. Keep in mind, you are **exploiting a safety net** and it is not going to be an effective solution for every height. The purpose of the `FrameLayout` in other solutions is to ensure the padding is discarded when your view is scaled and that safety net no longer applies.

Answer (score 60):

This is how I used Juozas's answer:

height of my `ProgressBar` is 4dp. So I created a `FrameLayout` with height 4dp and set the `layout_gravity` of `ProgressBar` to `center`. It's works like a charm.

```xml
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Note:** What a `FrameLayout` does is it clips away anything excess, so if you face the problem where the `ProgressBar` is still thin, just set the `layout_height` of the `ProgressBar` to some large number like `100dp`. It'll fully cover the FrameLayout and will only show `4dp` of it.

Comment: This is a good idea, but your code didn't work for me on Android 7.0 using the support library progress bar. The bar just became thinner but still had padding at the top.

Comment: @Sam Just make the ProgressBar e.g. height = 100dp. Due to the FrameLayout it still stays 4dp but the bar looks thicker.

Comment: Not workin on API 24+. The bar just gets thinner no matter the size we set on it.

Answer (score 40):

If someone still needs help can try this:

```xml
<androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />
```

Here, the progress bar is inside the *ConstraintLayout*, and the *constraintTop_toTopOf* and *constraintBottom_toTopOf* attributes must be applied to the same element (in this case, it is guideline).

***** COMPLETE SOLUTION:*****

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer as it works perfectly!

Comment: This is the right answer! You are compatible to all devices (which is not provided be negative margin) and android versions (which is not provided by frame layout solution). Also you do not have to do all that work that needed by importing the system drawables to the app (which does not provide a consistent UI across the system to all the android versions).

Comment: @Ali_Waris thanks for posting an answer, I'm keen to understand this solution as unable to get it working. Could you expand the answer to include the ConstraintLayout and guideline to the answer?

Comment: What is guideline here? Where will it go?

Comment: instead of guidline you can use empty view       
<View
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        android:id="@+id/guideline"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

Comment: How can we make its height bigger?

Comment: For me it also works without the guideline. All I needed to do was set _both_ constraint anchors to the bottom of the element wight above.

Answer (score 38):

I ended up using a custom library to solve this issue. Most of the other solutions work but the results are not consistent across various devices.

> **MaterialProgressBar**
>
> - Consistent appearance on Android 4.0+.
> - Correct tinting across platforms.
> - Able to remove the intrinsic padding of framework ProgressBar.
> - Able to hide the track of framework horizontal ProgressBar.
> - Used as a drop-in replacement for framework ProgressBar.

To add as a gradle dependency:

```
compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.7'
```

To add a ProgressBar with no intrinsic padding to your layout:

```
<me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    app:mpb_progressStyle="horizontal"
    app:mpb_useIntrinsicPadding="false"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialProgressBar.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />
```

`app:mpb_useIntrinsicPadding="false"` does the trick. For more details see the [GitHub page](https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/MaterialProgressBar).

Comment: First I tried to avoid to add another dependency just to remove some padding. But all other solutions failed in one or the other way/version and in the end this was like 3 minutes to make it work!! Thank you.

Comment: A whole library just to fix the padding on a view. Way to go Google.

Comment: You may want to use @style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal for the above (depending on your setup)

Answer (score 20):

To remove the vertial padding of `ProgressBar`, you can do by

- fix the height of `ProgressBar`
- Use scaleY="value" (value = height/4) (4 is default height of progress bar)

Example contains 1 wrap_content `ProgressBar`, 1 8dp `ProgressBar`, 1 100dp `ProgressBar`

[image]

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    ...
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:scaleY="2" />
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simplest solution!

Comment: Super! This is the simplest solution!

Answer (score 17):

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
    android:id="@+id/progress_loading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    app:indicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar_pdfview"/>
```

I am using this new progress bar using this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

- trackThickness: the thickness of the indicator and track.
- indicatorColor: the color(s) of the indicator.
- trackColor: the color of the track.
- trackCornerRadius: the radius of the rounded corner of the indicator
  and track.
- indeterminateAnimationType: the type of indeterminate animation.
- indicatorDirectionLinear: the sweeping direction of the indicator.

[image: see result of this horizontal progress bar]

Comment: Use 1.3.0-rc01 now. Its released.

Comment: the best way for 2021

Answer (score 15):

It's possible to draw vertically centered ProgressBar inside a parent that would clip away the padding. Since ProgressBar cannot draw itself bigger than parent, we must create a big parent to place inside a clipping view.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/clippedProgressBar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:indeterminate="true"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This worked on Android 7.0, but it resulted in no progress bar on my Sony Xperia M running Android 4.1.2.

Comment: @Sam thanks for reporting! What do you see if you change the height of the first FrameLayout from 4dp to 48dp?

Comment: The progress bar appears, but it has a lot of padding underneath it and a tiny bit of padding above it.

Comment: @Sam I've updated my answer, hopefully it will work acceptably on your Sony device. If it does not help, I suggest reviewing your application theme configuration. Using Holo theme on KitKat should fix it.

Answer (score 14):

A complete solution to this problem would be as follows. Just in case if someone needs code fragments, this is what I did.

1. Copied all the 8 indeterminate horizontal progressbar drawables
2. Edited the drawables using some image manipulator and remove unnecessary paddings
3. Copied the drawable XML named progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo.xml from android platform
4. Copied the style Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal and its parents
5. Set the style and min_height manually in the layout

Here is the progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo.xml

```
<animation-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo5" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo6" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo7" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate_holo8" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

Style resources copied to my local styles file.

```
<style name="Widget">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:attr/textAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">true</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateBehavior">repeat</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDuration">3500</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo</item>
</style>
```

And finally, set min height to 4dp in my local layout file.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb_loading"
    style="@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:minHeight="4dp"
    android:minWidth="48dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo" />
```

Comment: From where can we copy the drawable mentioned in step 1: "1.Copied all the 8 indeterminate horizontal progressbar drawables"?

Comment: @JeffreyLin I copied it from this location `<your-sdk-folder>/platforms/android-17/data/res/drawable-hdpi/`

Comment: Isn't it amazing how much work you have to do to achieve such a common sense behaviour that should just come by default in Android?

Comment: And for material design ?

Comment: @aat I don't think material guidelines has similar progressbars. Please go through this document : https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/progress-activity.html#progress-activity-types-of-indicators

Comment: @Spacemonkey because, it is simply Google.

Answer (score 10):

I met the same problem while using progressbar with Horizontal style.

The root cause is that the default 9-patch drawable for progress bar:
(progress_bg_holo_dark.9.png) has some vertical transparent pixels as padding.

The final Solution that worked for me: customize the progress drawable, my sample code as follow:

**custom_horizontal_progressbar_drawable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#33ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#ff9800" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#E91E63" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**layout snippet:**

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/song_progress_normal"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_horizontal_progressbar_drawable"
    android:progress="0"/>
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution. Your example code produced no progress bar on my Sony Xperia M running Android 4.1.2, though.

Answer (score 8):

One trick is to add negative margins to your progress bar.

Below is an example of the XML code, assuming it's on top of your screen:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
    android:indeterminate="true" />
```

[image: result of code]

Comment: Adding negative margins solved the problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

if someone still searching for a solution -- check this comment

set the minimum height to be ***4 dp***

```
   android:minHeight="4dp"
```

-

```
  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/web_view_progress_bar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:min="0"
    android:progress="5"
    android:minHeight="4dp"
    android:progressTint="@color/vodafone_red"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:progress="60" />
```

Comment: I prefer this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Subin's answer seems to be the only one (currently) that isn't a fragile hack subject to breakage in future releases of the Android ProgressBar.

But rather than going through the trouble of breaking out the resources, modifying them, and maintaining them indefinitely, I've opted to use the [MaterialProgressBar library](https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/MaterialProgressBar), which does that for us:

```
<me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    custom:mpb_progressStyle="horizontal"
    custom:mpb_showTrack="false"
    custom:mpb_useIntrinsicPadding="false"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialProgressBar.ProgressBar.Horizontal.NoPadding"
/>
```

In build.gradle:

```
// Android horizontal ProgressBar doesn't allow removal of top/bottom padding
compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.6'
```

That project has a [nice demo](https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/MaterialProgressBar/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/main_activity.xml) that shows the differences between it and the built-in ProgressBar.

Answer (score 2):

I use minHeight and maxHeigh. It helps for different Api versions.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="3dp"
    android:minHeight="3dp" />
```

It needs to use both. Api 23 works nice with

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="0dp"
```

But lower Api versions increase progress bar height to maxHeight in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:progress="25"
    android:progressTint="@color/colorWhite"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp" />
```

... and then configure the progress bar to your needs since it'll initially display a mid-sized bar with a yellow-colored progress tint with a grayish progress background tint. Also, notice that there's no vertical padding.

Answer (score 2):

Use like this, inside Linearlayout

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:background="#efefef"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <ProgressBar
         android:id="@+id/progressBar"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:indeterminate="true"
         android:visibility="gone"
         android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
         style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Works great! Next time describe what you code does and what changes did you to. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

For me this is working. Progress bar is sharp. It fits perfectly. I tried with different heights of frame and progress.

```
<FrameLayout             
    android:layout_width="match_parent"             
    android:layout_height="4dp">    

   <ProgressBar
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="16dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:indeterminate="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFXzR.png)

Answer (score 1):

adding the android:progressDrawable to a layer-list defined in drawable fixed the issue for me. It works by masking the progess bar in a custom drawable

example implementation described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4454450/1145905

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"` and it was fairly easy to get rid of the margins.  That style is:

```
    <item name="progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_material</item>
    <item name="indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal_material</item>
    <item name="minHeight">16dip</item>
    <item name="maxHeight">16dip</item>
```

I just overrode the min/max height:

```
    <ProgressBar
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:minHeight="2dp"
        android:maxHeight="2dp" />
```

Comment: I never was satisified with the generic progress bar and turned to a library in the end:

me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary to download any new module or even put a FrameLayout around your Progress Bar. These are all just hacks. Only 2 steps:

In your whatever.xml

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/workoutSessionGlobalProgress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="YOUR_HEIGHT"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_horizontal"
    android:progress="0"
    <!-- High value to make ValueAnimator smoother -->
    android:max="DURATION * 1000"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialProgressBar.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>
```

progress_horizontal.xml, Change the values as you please.

Don't like the rounded corners? 
 Remove corner radius

Don't like the colors? Change the colors, etc.
Done!

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                    android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#ff747674"
                    android:angle="270"
                    />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                        android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                        android:centerY="0.75"
                        android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                        android:angle="270"
                        />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#ffffd300"
                        android:centerColor="#ffffb600"
                        android:centerY="0.75"
                        android:endColor="#ffffcb00"
                        android:angle="270"
                        />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Generally, these are the steps to change the code of anything you don't like. Just find the source code and figure out what to change. If you follow the ProgressBar source code, you will find a file called progress_horizontal.xml that it references. Basically how I solve all my XML problems.

Answer (score 1):

Just make use of Material ProgressIndicator which has no hidden margin.

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.ProgressIndicator
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ProgressIndicator.Linear.Indeterminate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:indicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:trackColor="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Comment: ProgressIndicator will be deprecated https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/ProgressIndicator.md

Comment: you can use this 'com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator'

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/white"
        android:max="100"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:indeterminate="true"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: Please don't simply post code. Give some context to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

set height value you want in java file, most important is setMaxHeight.

```
progressBar.setMinHeight(heightYouWant);
progressBar.setMaxHeight(heightYouWant);
```

it work for me!

Comment: It requires API level 29

Answer (score -1):

A simple no-tricks solution which is compatible with any version of Android and doesn't need external libraries is faking `ProgressBar` with two `Views` inside `LinearLayout`. This is what I ended up with. Looks pretty neat and this approach is quite flexible - you can animate it in funky ways, add text etc.

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/inventory_progress_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inventory_progress_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inventory_progress_remaining"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
public void setProgressValue(float percentage) {
    TextView progressValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inventory_progress_value);
    TextView progressRemaining = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inventory_progress_remaining);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsValue = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsRemaining = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    paramsValue.weight = (100 - percentage);
    paramsRemaining.weight = percentage;

    progressValue.setLayoutParams(paramsValue);
    progressRemaining.setLayoutParams(paramsRemaining);

}
```

Result (with some elevation added):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The best solution should be

```
android:minHeight="0dp"
```

No workaround and works like a charm.

Comment: didn't worked, can you please explain why this should work ?

Comment: @humble_wolf It worked for myself in my previous project when I wrote the answer; might be dependent on some particular version of library? It should work because the reason there is a padding like thing for progress bar is not the actual padding but there’s a `minHeight` that’s bigger than 0 (say 32dp maybe) predefined. By change this property you get a different look.

Comment: Didn't worked for me in Inderminate=true mode, maybe working in determinate mode. If you really want this to be an answer please write the explaination in answer  with all the conditions.

Answer (score -1):

One simple way to move the Progressbar up that does not require any additional views or fiddling with the margins is to use the attribute `android:translationZ`

That way you could either use it in the XML

```
<Progressbar
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:translateY="-6dp"
/>
```

**or**

use it from within a style

```
<style name="MyTheme.Progressbar.Horizontal" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Progressbar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:translateY">-6dp</item>
</style>
```

and then reference it in the Layout like this

```
<Progressbar
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 style="@style/MyTheme.Progressbar.Horizontal"
 />
```

Answer (score -1):

Make the size of the progressBar really big (i mean height) and then place it into a frameLayout of the size that you wish your progressBar needs to be.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/white" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple material horizontal progress bar **without adding a file, scaling, or changing the dimension**

```
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:progressTint="Your Progress Color"
    android:progressTintMode="src_over"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="Your Background Color"
    android:backgroundTintMode="src_over"
```

This works by coloring over the progress or background color presented in `Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal`