# Horizontal progress bar is not visible if placed above toolbar (For Android 5)

Tags: android

I tried to place horizontal progress bar on the top of toolbar by having the following XML.

### my_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Toolbar -->
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171471/remove-vertical-padding-from-horizontal-progressbar -->
        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_gravity="top"

            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"

            android:progress="2000"
            android:max="10000" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar2"
            android:layout_gravity="top"

            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"

            android:progress="2000"
            android:max="10000" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

### toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    <!-- android:elevation="4dp" is used due to http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android- -->

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This works absolutely fine under Android 4+. Here's the screenshot for Android 4+

[image]

However, when it comes to Android 5+, the horizontal progress bar is not visible on the top of toolbar.

[image]

If I remove line

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

I will get the following screenshot in Android 5+

[image]

It seems that the top progress bar is blocked by toolbar? But, I thought within `FrameLayout`, the progress bar is having higher z-order than toolbar?

May I know, how I can make horizontal progress bar visible if placed above toolbar, in Android 5+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Android 5.0+ devices, elevation is taken into account when determining the z-order of components - those with a higher elevation are visibly above those with a lower elevation, even if the higher elevation item is declared earlier in the XML file (normally causing it to be behind).

You can add an elevation to your `ProgressBar`, matching the elevation of the `Toolbar` - that will ensure that the same z-ordering works as in previous versions of Android.

Comment: That's a great tip! I had been spending quite some time to experiment various technique like `bringToFront` in order to raise the z-order of progress bar. They fail. Your suggestion works just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

       // try to set your progress bar here
       // on top of the toolbar

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But, I don't want progress bar to consume toolbar's space. i.e., top progress bar shouldn't "push down" toolbar.

Comment: But, LinearLayout will push the toolbar down. I don't want to push the toolbar down. I want progress bar to overlap with toolbar, with progress bar having higher z-order.

Comment: That's why I've post with a RelativeLayout. If your place your progressbar on top of the toolbar you will only need Visibility.GONE and Visibility.VISIBLE to be on top of the toolbar. RelativeLayout will not push down the toolbar

Comment: What is the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` should be used? As I never came across RelativeLayout which allows stack overlapping.

Comment: You'll not need LayoutParams to this task. Place the progress bar right on the comment section of my code example. It'll work as you want. For a better look, put the progress bar with match width and a defined height (to make sure it doesn't mess with the toolbar in any way)

Comment: I tested in Android 5. It won't work. Toolbar is still blocking the visibility of progress bar.

Comment: Are you using an ActionbarActivity? What theme are you using? Lollipop gives a huge importance to the toolbar.

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` is being used. Theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` is being used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89097/discussion-between-mariano-zorrilla-and-cheok-yan-cheng).