# changing size of Android's default progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar, progress

I'm using the default Android's progress bar :

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
```

It is displayed like this :

[image]

I just want to make it a bit bigger (raise its height) with minimal actions. Is it possible?
Tried doing minHeight and maxHeight, didn't help..

Thank you.

Comment: share your xml file.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="CustomProgressBarHorizontal" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
      <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_progress_bar_horizontal</item>
      <item name="android:minHeight">10dip</item>
      <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
</style>
```

source [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13510123/2169192)

Comment: @BVtp, this is an acepted answer?