# NativeScript's Intellisense (Android) - is not showing some methods?

Tags: android, angular, webstorm, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Using WebStorm, I have a `Progress` element :

```
<Progress  id="prgressid" ></Progress>
```

I want to increase its height. It can be done via `scaleY=".."` attribute or [**via native code**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27301074/859154) :

```
mProgressBar.setScaleY(3);
```

I've decided to do it via code but the intellisene shows me :

[image]

[Another try without `.android.`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J62o8.png)

It doesn't have the `setScaleY` method.
(*if I try to use `setScale` method - it fails at runtime - But if I try `setScaleY` - it does work.*)

**Question:**

Why isn't the method shown ? And what should I see in order to see all accessible methods ?

`tns info` :

[image]

[Sdk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzGJO.png)

Comment: Do you get the auto completion for `this.page.getViewById( id: "prgressid" ).setScale...`? The NativeScript View class should also have those methods, so you don't need `.android` for that. I have no idea where the `setScale()` is coming from though.

Comment: @xander No I don't : https://i.stack.imgur.com/J62o8.png , Also it shows an error ( if I don't specify android : https://i.stack.imgur.com/EObaj.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: the initial snippet had an error - in fact, you can access the public methods `setScaleY` and `setScaleX` but you will need the typings (via [tns-platform-declarations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations)) and also we would need to cast the native component to `android.widget.ProgressBar` (otherwise it would be of type `any`)

For example:

```
<Progress value="50" loaded="onPbLoaded" />
```

TypeScript

```
export function onPbLoaded(args) {
    let pb = <Progress>args.object;

    if(isAndroid) {
        let nativeProgress = <android.widget.ProgressBar>pb.android; // android.widget.ProgressBar{d26eea9 V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0}
        console.log("nativeProgress Android: " + nativeProgress); 

        nativeProgress.setScaleX(3);
        nativeProgress.setScaleY(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer revised ^^^